# No JavaScript and Metro app templates in VS2012 Ultimate RC on Win 7

Tags: visual-studio

Hi there I have installed VS2012 Ultimate RC on Win 7. But it does not show the project templates for Metro style app for VB and C#, & nothing for JavaScript. Is it necessary to install this VS on Win 8 RC, then only it will show up the templates for Metro and Javascript. Or is there a separate version of VS for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Win8 development is only supported on Win8. VS installs on any Windows OS from Vista onwards to support classic app development, but as you see you won't have access to the Win8 app styles.

Since Win8 rc is available for free, you can download it and install it on a virtual machine and code on that for a low cost workaround. You don't need to have it be your primary OS. Developing in a VM has a ton of benefits, but that's not what you asked so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I installed Win8 RC in VHD. Whats the benefit of installing and developing in VM?

Comment: @Mahesha999 The benefit is separating your personal use computer from your development machine. If you develop in a virtual machine, it lets you do 1. switching physical machines or reinstalling without touching your development environment or 2. changing development environments without touching your physical machine. For instance, if your VS install is screwed up, you may have to reinstall Windows to get it working again. If you're developing on a VM, you don't have to touch your email, etc.